# How to browse the files only with extensions .xls using JFileChooser in swing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am trying to open a browse window using JFileChooser in java swing . 
By default its showing the all extension files when i browse the directory.
But my requirement is

```
 JFileChooser should browse the files with specific extensions.
```

Comment: FileNameExtensionFilter ???

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try that:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("XLS files", "xls");
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```